# Blank bar at top of toolbar in Android Marshmallow

Tags: android

Got an empty white bar at the top of toolbar only in Android MarshMallow Versions.
All other android versions are set to display correctly.

Comment: Did you tried to use NoActionBar theme and providing Toolbar through layout?

Comment: i am using the same theme bro..

Comment: Sorry didn't notice include tag.

Comment: If you remove FrameLayout, does it change anything?

Comment: it's ok,do you have any idea about this error?

Comment: no change with that

Comment: you have to make your `DrawerLayout` as `parent` and put `CoordinateLayout` inside it.

Comment: No,still there is no change,but due to change of drawer layout as root it comes out at empty space .. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is raised due to usage of BottomBar plugin in my code https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar
The issue is straightaway solved in documentation

> Why does the top of my content have sooooo much empty space?!
>
> Probably because you're doing some next-level advanced Android stuff (such as using CoordinatorLayout and fitsSystemWindows="true") and the normal paddings for the content are too much. Add this right after calling attach():
>
> mBottomBar.noTopOffset();

Comment: **thank you very much**, I was pulling hairs out of my head, I couldn't find out what was the matter!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `DrawerLayout` as `parent` of all. So put `DrawerLayout` as I posted Answer on below. This is the basic Structure I post it.

**Just an Example :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/app_nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: No,still there is no change,but due to change of drawer layout as root it comes out at empty space .. :(

Comment: @VenkatRamana Compare the Structure your are doing it totally wrong way ?

Comment: No it works perfectly in all other android versions,the problem is only with marshmallow versions

Comment: @VenkatRamana see this demo you will get the idea how to set up layout https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: @VenkatRamana I think your your java code is good but the problem is in Layout file.

Comment: Sorry @Ironman i didn't find any,did you?the given git hub repo link didn't use CoordinatorLayout,I think the it is problem with CoordinatorLayout..

Comment: @VenkatRamana see `activity_main.xml` there are include this file `include_list_viewpager` when you open it show `CoordinateLayout`.

Comment: Thanks!! but it results the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you added **android:fitsSystemWindows="true"** to your parent?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--Toolbar-->
         <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!--================ CONTENT ================-->
            <!-- PUT SOMETHING -->
        <!--/ ================ END CONTENT ================-->
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <!--Drawer-->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_base"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_base_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```